# Laravel 8 Method Not Allowed 405 Ajax CRUD

Tags: laravel

I fixed my csrf
I fixed my route , route clear too

but still error show up .

I'm doing ajax form in modal :

My Route

```
Route::post('increp/store',[\App\Http\Controllers\IncrepController::class,'store'])->name('increp.store');
```

My ajax

```
            // Create article Ajax request.
            $('#submit_increp').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $("#main-form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('increp.store') }}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $(document).find('span.error-text').text('');
                    
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        if(result.errors) {
                            console.log(result.errors);
                            $('.alert-danger').html('');
                            $.each(result.errors, function(key, val) {
                                $('span.'+key+'_error').text(val[0]);
                         
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('.alert-danger').hide();
                            $('.alert-success').show();
                          
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

I doing this for days, i dont have idea how to fix this errors .

Network tab
[image]

Console tab

[image]

Comment: Do you use Sanctum or Passport to allow API calls?

Comment: Can you please post the error here as well for better understanding of the question?

Comment: Open your browser network tab and see if there are any redirects happening on that request.

Comment: make sure you are sending the csrf token as part of the data that the form submits or at least use the following to setup it.
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

Comment: Error in browser :
toastr.js:474 POST http://xyz.test/increp/store 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: @Danish I already updated my question

Comment: can you give us the example of the form you're trying to submit?

Comment: In your data object you are passing  csrf token as well ? 
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "data": data
        }